# ProgressDialog won't dismiss if I switch to another application even if the IntentService has finished

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, progressdialog, intentservice

In my app I use a IntentService to run a long process(send data to a server)

### This is the code for the activity that starts the IntentService.

```
public class SendDataActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public static final String ACTION_SEND_DATA = "com.ss.quickorder.SEND_DATA";
    
    private Button mSendDataButton;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;   

    // define instance variable for the broadcast receiver
    private SendDataReceiver sendDataReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enviar_datos);

        mSendDataButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendDataButton);       
        mSendDataButton.setOnClickListener(this);   

    }   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // here get SharedPreferences and send them with the Intent
        Intent inputIntent = new Intent(SendDataActivity.this,
                SendaDataService.class);        
        // Display progress to the user
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Sending Data",
                "This might take a few minutes, please wait...", true);
        startService(inputIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(this);

        localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(sendDataReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(
                SendDataActivity.ACTION_SEND_DATA);
        sendDataReceiver = new SendDataReceiver();

        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(this);
        localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(sendDataReceiver,
                broadcastFilter);
    }

    // define an inner class for the broadcast receiver
    class SendDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("QuickOrder", "Broadcast received!!!");
            //get data from intent
            boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);
            // Clear progress indicator
            SendDataActivity.this.mProgress.dismiss();
            String message;
            if (success) {
                message = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("resultado",0));
            } else {
                message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Log.d("QuickOrder", "An error has occurred:-->" + message);
            }

            // update the display

            Toast.makeText(SendDataActivity.this,
                     message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

The process runs in the background as expected and when it finishes I use a LocalBroadcastManager to send some data back to the activity that called the IntenService

### This is the code for the IntentService

```
public class SendDataService extends IntentService {
    private static final String NAME = "SendDataService";
    
    public SendDataService() {
        super(NAME);
        // We don’t want intents redelivered
        // in case we’re shut down unexpectedly
        setIntentRedelivery(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {  
        // get NetworkInfo object
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // if network is connected, download data
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            String message = "";
            int result=0;           
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                //send data to the server               
                success=true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                success=false;
                message=e.getMessage();             
            }
            Intent broadCasIntent=new Intent();
            broadCasIntent.setAction(SendDataActivity.ACTION_SEND_DATA);
            broadCasIntent.putExtra("success", success);        
            broadCasIntent.putExtra("result", result);
            broadCasIntent.putExtra("message", message);
            
            LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager=LocalBroadcastManager
                    .getInstance(this);
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(broadCasIntent);
            
        }   
        
    }   
}
```

As you can see above in the **SendDataActivity** activity  I have created a inner class that extends the BroadcastReceiver class and within that class I dismiss the ProgressDialog.

### The code for the BroadcastReceiver within the SendDataActivity

```
    class SendDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("QuickOrder", "Broadcast received!!!");
            //get data from intent
            boolean success = intent.getBooleanExtra("success", false);
            // Clear progress indicator
            SendDataActivity.this.mProgress.dismiss(); //This doesn't work If I switch to another application
            String message;
            if (success) {
                message = String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("resultado",0));
            } else {
                message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Log.d("QuickOrder", "An error has occurred:-->" + message);
            }

            // update the display

            Toast.makeText(SendDataActivity.this,
                     message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

With the code shown above everything works as expected **so long I stay in the application**, but the problem comes if I switch to another application or if I receive a phone call and then come back to my application.There I still find the ProgressDialog **as it the IntentService  would still be running** and I'm 100% sure that is has finished, because I can see the result in the LogCat console and in the database.

Is there any problem with ProgressDialogs in these kind of scenarios? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to `unregisterReceiver` receiver in `onDestory` instead of in `onPause`

Comment: How could I check if the service has finished so that I can dismiss the ProgressDialog?? I think I need to do that on `onResume`

Comment: Thank you very much @ρяσѕρєяK it worked!! The problem now it's that I'm confused. The book I read says that we should unregister a receiver in Activity.onPause() and [the doc seems to agree](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) , but that was the reason I didn't get the desired result. Do you think you could explain this a title bit more.

Comment: You could use SharedPreferences to keep a boolean value indicating whether the service is running, check it in `onResume()`, and close the ProgressDialog if necessary. This way, you can keep `unregisterReceiver()` in `onPause()`, which is probably preferable.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. Please tell me, how can I do that? how can I use SharedPreference in this case? From the little I know the only way my activity and the service have to communicate with each other is via a BroadcastReceiver and if I unregister the receiver on `Activity.onPause()` , then the Application has no way to tell whether the service is still running or not while it is on the **paused state**

Comment: @MikeM. Bound services seem to be the way to go here, but I didn't use a bound service because all the sources I have read says that once the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys the service. [Even the doc says so.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) Unless, we can implement a mixture of a bound an unbound service

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that once your `IntentService` has processed your `Intent`, it's use is done and it will send the broadcast and Android will kill that `IntentService`. It's what it does, process an `Intent`.

Now, if your `Activity` was paused, there is no way it could have processed the `Broadcast` sent by your `IntentService`, and it can't query your `IntentService`, because they can't be bound to your `Activity`.

What I suggest is: use a [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). Your `Activity` can start the `Service` in the `onClick()` and then use `bindService()` to have a variable that references your service. You could also bind to the `Service` in your `onResume()` to check whether it has any running operations or not, and show/dismiss the `ProgressDialog` accordingly.

As soon as your `Activity` has a dependency on your `IntentService`, you should step up to a `Bound Service`.

Comment: Thank you @tolgap for taking the time to answer. Well, I have thought of using a bound service too, but since I want my service to survive the application I ended up using a IntentService. Please tell, what problem can come from not unregistering the receiver on `Activity.onPause()` ??

Comment: I would want to tell you that the issue lies in `unregisterReceiver`, but it does not. That's not the issue. But it could cause for your `Receiver` to "leak". As in, still listen to broadcasts when the `Context` has been removed/destroyed.

Comment: @eddy also, `Bound Services` will survive `Activity` lifecycles. I use them all the time for this purpose. These services are also called `Foreground Services`.

Comment: Really?? Could you tell me how to implement such a service, because all the sources I have read says that once the last client unbinds from the service, the system **destroys** the service. [Even the doc says so](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). Unless, we can implement a mixture of a bound an unbound service

Comment: @eddy the docs are pretty clear about `Foreground Services`. It's when a `Service` is going to do an operation that the user is aware of. A `Foreground Service` usually has to show a notification to make the user aware of it's presence. Just use the link I provided in my answer. I can't implement your entire code. By the way, this change is quite a minimal change.

Comment: then why they always says that about Bound Services? Aren't they really destroyed when the app that started them is destroyed? Sorry if I asked too many questions, but this is kind of confusing to me :S

Comment: You are correct yes, but that's not the case if you start your `Service` using `startForeground()`.

Answer (score 0):

Dismiss the progress dialog in onResume.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```